# C# - To support string datatype in Modbus protocol using NModbus4

Tags: c#, modbus

We are using NModbus4.dll ( version 2.1.0.0 ) for implementing Modbus protocol in our OPC server.
We are supporting integer and booloean data type.
We want to support string data type. We are not sure which API to be used for supporting string data type.
Please suggest

Example:
We use the API ReadCoils() for reading data from boolean data type tags/items
We use the API ReadHoldingRegisters() for reading data from integer data type tags/items

Thanks
Antoni

Answer (score 0):

The modbus protocol does not support strings, which is why there is no API.  Some devices will store strings in multiple input or holding registers, but you'll need to check with the device's register table to determine how they are encoded.  For example, you may find that they use one holding register per character, ASCII encoded.

You will most likely need to use ReadHoldingRegisters to get the data, then decode it into a string.